# PySimpleGUI window doesn't resize to previous window size after changing layouts

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pysimplegui

I have created a GUI that displays Different layouts when you select one in the menu.
When i enter the Dashboard layout and enter after that to a regular layout it doesn't resize to its original size like the other two.
(video link is provided for further explanation)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKUOAJqAeUY

any solution?

```
    import _thread
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
    import paramiko
    import math
    # pylint: disable=C0103 ,W0612, C0301, R1722
    
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    
    def ssh_connect(HOSTNAME,key_num):
        print(HOSTNAME)
        '''Connect to SDR with mobaxterm SSH connection'''
        hostname = HOSTNAME
        username = "air"
        password = "d1password1"
        port = 22
        # add to known hosts
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        try:
            window[f'-LOG-{key_num}'].update("Trying to Connect..." + '\n', append=True)
            client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password, port=port)
            print(f"Connected to SSH - IP :  {hostname}  Nashville")
            window[f'-LOG-{key_num}'].update(f"Connected to SSH - IP :  {hostname}" + '\n', append=True)
        except ValueError as error:
            print("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server")
            window[f'-LOG-{key_num}'].update("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server" + '\n', append=True)
            exit()
    
    def system_time():
        '''Takes the system time from mobaxterm SSH connection'''
        stdinn, start, stderrr = client.exec_command("date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N'")
        sys_time = start.read().decode()
        return sys_time
    
    def App_loger():
        '''Data collection proccess'''
        global stop                 # New statement
        start_time = system_time()
        accumulated_detections = 0
        while not stop:  # New statement
            stop_time = system_time()
            stdin, grep, stderr = client.exec_command(f"cat /var/log/enforce-air/enforce-air.log |"
                                                      " grep -E 'DL: Chain: 11, Task: Detect.*F: '|"
                                                      f"awk -v 'start={start_time}' -v end='{stop_time}' "
                                                      "'/^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} ""/"" {inrange = $0 >= start && $0 <= end } inrange' |"
                                                      "awk -F '|' '{print $7}' |awk -F ',' '{print $8 ',' $12}'")
            x = grep.read().decode()
            x = x.split('\n')
            if len(x) > 1:
                for line in x:
                    window['-LOG-1'].update(line + '\n', append=True)
    
            accumulated_detections = accumulated_detections + len(x) - 1
            window['-NUM_OF_DETECTIONS-1'].update(str(accumulated_detections))
            # window.refresh()
            start_time = stop_time
    
    def log_finder_grep(cus_grep):
        '''Data collection proccess'''
        global stop_4                # New statement
        custom_grep = cus_grep
        start_time = system_time()
        accumulated_detections = 0
        while not stop_4:  # New statement
            stop_time = system_time()
            stdin, grep, stderr = client.exec_command(f"cat /var/log/enforce-air/enforce-air.log |"
                                                      f" grep -E '{custom_grep}'|"
                                                      f"awk -v 'start={start_time}' -v end='{stop_time}' "
                                                      "'/^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} ""/"" {inrange = $0 >= start && $0 <= end } inrange'")
            y = grep.read().decode()
            y = y.split('\n')
            if len(y) > 1:
                for line in y:
                    window['-LOG-4'].update(line + '\n', append=True)
    
            accumulated_detections = accumulated_detections + len(y) - 1
            window['-NUM_OF_DETECTIONS-1'].update(str(accumulated_detections))
            # window.refresh()
            start_time = stop_time
    
    
    theme_dict = {'BACKGROUND': '#2B475D',
                    'TEXT': '#FFFFFF',
                    'INPUT': '#F2EFE8',
                    'TEXT_INPUT': '#000000',
                    'SCROLL': '#F2EFE8',
                    'BUTTON': ('#000000', '#C2D4D8'),
                    'PROGRESS': ('#FFFFFF', '#C7D5E0'),
                    'BORDER': 1,'SLIDER_DEPTH': 0, 'PROGRESS_DEPTH': 0}
    sg.LOOK_AND_FEEL_TABLE['Dashboard'] = theme_dict
    sg.theme('Dashboard')
    BORDER_COLOR = '#C7D5E0'
    DARK_HEADER_COLOR = '#1B2838'
    BPAD_TOP = ((20,20), (20, 10))
    BPAD_LEFT = ((20,10), (0, 10))
    BPAD_LEFT_INSIDE = ((0, 10),(0, 10))
    BPAD_RIGHT = ((10,20), (10, 20))
    
    menu_def = [['Apps', ['SSH Logger', 'FSPL Calculator', 'Log By Grep', 'Exit APP', ]],
                ['Edit', ['Paste', ['Special', 'Normal', ], 'Undo'], ],
                ['Help', 'About...'], ]
    
    top_banner = [[sg.Text('Enter HostName'), sg.InputText(size=(15, 1), key='HOSTNAME_4'),
                     sg.Button('Connect to SSH', key='Connect to SSH 4', size=(15, 1))],
                  [sg.Text('Enter Grep'), sg.InputText(size=(100, 10), key='custom_grep')]]
    
    block_3 = [ [sg.Button('Drone_Detect',key='drone_detect_button', size=(29, 1))],
                [sg.Button('RC_Detect',key='rc_detect_button', size=(29, 1))],
                [sg.Button('1',key='1', size=(29, 1))],
                [sg.Button('2',key='2', size=(29, 1))],
                [sg.Button('3',key='3', size=(29, 1))],
                [sg.Button('4',key='4', size=(29, 1))],
                [sg.Button('5',key='5', size=(29, 1))],
                [sg.Button('6',key='6', size=(29, 1))],
               [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]]
    
    block_2 = [[sg.Button('Run', key='Run_4'), sg.Button('Stop', key='Stop_4'),sg.Button('Exit', key='Exit_4', button_color=('white', 'red'))],
               [sg.Text('accumulated_detections'), sg.Multiline(size=(8, 1), key='-NUM_OF_DETECTIONS-1', do_not_clear=True, autoscroll=True, auto_refresh=True, write_only=False, disabled=True)]]
    
    block_4 = [[sg.Multiline(size=(116, 33), key='-LOG-4', do_not_clear=True, autoscroll=True, auto_refresh=True, write_only=False, disabled=True)]]
    
    FSPL_Calculator_layout = [[sg.Text('Enter Freq[Ghz]   '), sg.InputText(key='-DIST-', size=(8, 1)), sg.Text('Result[dBm]:'),
                               sg.Multiline(size=(8, 1), key='result', do_not_clear=True, autoscroll=True, auto_refresh=True, write_only=False, disabled=True)],
                              [sg.Text('Enter Distance[m]'), sg.InputText(key='-FREQ-', size=(8, 1))],
                              [sg.Button('Calculate', size=(10, 1)), sg.Button('Exit', key='Exit_3 ', size=(10, 1))]]
    
    Parser_log_yariv = [[sg.Text('Enter HostName'), sg.InputText(size=(15, 1), key='HOSTNAME_1'),
                 sg.Button('Connect to SSH', key='Connect to SSH 1', size=(15, 1))],
                [sg.Multiline(size=(50, 20), key='-LOG-1', do_not_clear=True, autoscroll=True, auto_refresh=True,
                              write_only=False, disabled=True)],
                [sg.Text('accumulated_detections'),
                 sg.Multiline(size=(8, 1), key='-NUM_OF_DETECTIONS-1', do_not_clear=True, autoscroll=True,
                              auto_refresh=True, write_only=False, disabled=True),
                 sg.Button('Run', key='Run_1'), sg.Button('Stop', key='Stop_1'),
                 sg.Button('Exit', key='Exit_1', button_color=('white', 'red'))]]
    
    Open_image_layout = [[sg.Image('image.png', size=(400, 400))]]
    
    
    
    
    layout = [[[sg.Column(FSPL_Calculator_layout, key='FSPL_Calc', visible=False),
               sg.Column(Open_image_layout, key='Open_image', visible=True),sg.Column(Parser_log_yariv, key='Parser_log_yariv', visible=False),
               sg.Column(top_banner, size=(1120, 70), pad=(20, 0), background_color=DARK_HEADER_COLOR, key='log_by_grep_1', visible=False)],
               [sg.Column([[sg.Column(block_2, size=(250, 80), pad=BPAD_LEFT_INSIDE, key='log_by_grep_2', visible=False)],
                          [sg.Column(block_3, size=(250, 450), pad=BPAD_LEFT_INSIDE)]], pad=BPAD_LEFT,
                         background_color=BORDER_COLOR, key='log_by_grep_3', visible=False),
               sg.Column(block_4, size=(850, 550), pad=BPAD_RIGHT, key='log_by_grep_4', visible=False)]],
              [sg.Menu(menu_def)]]
    window = sg.Window('Dashboard PySimpleGUI-Style', layout, margins=(0,0), background_color=BORDER_COLOR, no_titlebar=True, grab_anywhere=True)
    
    stop = False
    while True:             # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == 'SSH Logger':
            window['log_by_grep_1'].update(visible=False)
            window['log_by_grep_2'].update(visible=False)
            window['log_by_grep_3'].update(visible=False)
            window['log_by_grep_4'].update(visible=False)
            window['FSPL_Calc'].update(visible=False)
            window['Parser_log_yariv'].update(visible=True)
            window['Open_image'].update(visible=False)
        if event == "Connect to SSH 1":
            ssh_connect(values['HOSTNAME_1'],'1')
        if event == "Run_1":
            stop = False  # New statement
            window['Run_1'].update(button_color=('black', 'yellow'))
            _thread.start_new_thread(App_loger, ())  # New statement
        if event == "Stop_1":
            stop = True  # New statement
        if event == "Exit_1" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            window.Close()  # New statement
            break
    ########################################################################################################################
        if event == 'FSPL Calculator':
            window['log_by_grep_1'].update(visible=False)
            window['log_by_grep_2'].update(visible=False)
            window['log_by_grep_3'].update(visible=False)
            window['log_by_grep_4'].update(visible=False)
            window['FSPL_Calc'].update(visible=True)
            window['Parser_log_yariv'].update(visible=False)
            window['Open_image'].update(visible=False)
        if event == "Calculate":
            freq = values['-FREQ-']
            dist = values['-DIST-']
            print(values['-FREQ-'])
            FSPL = 20 * math.log(float(freq) * 1000000000, 10) + 20 * math.log(float(dist), 10) - 147.55
            FSPL = round(FSPL, 2)
            window['result'].update(str(FSPL))
        if event == "Exit_3 " or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            window.Close()  # New statement
            break
    ########################################################################################################################
        if event == 'Log By Grep':
            window['log_by_grep_1'].update(visible=True)
            window['log_by_grep_2'].update(visible=True)
            window['log_by_grep_3'].update(visible=True)
            window['log_by_grep_4'].update(visible=True)
            window['FSPL_Calc'].update(visible=False)
            window['Parser_log_yariv'].update(visible=False)
            window['Open_image'].update(visible=False)
            print(layout)
        if event == "Connect to SSH 4":
            ssh_connect(values['HOSTNAME_4'],'4')
        if event == "drone_detect_button":
            stop_4 = False  # New statement
            values['custom_grep'] = 'drone_detect'
            args = (values['custom_grep'])
            _thread.start_new_thread(log_finder_grep, (args,))
        if event == "Run_4":
            stop_4 = False  # New statement
            window['Run_4'].update(button_color=('black', 'yellow'))
            args = (values['custom_grep'])
            _thread.start_new_thread(log_finder_grep, (args, ))  # New statement
        if event == "Stop_4":
            stop_4 = True
        if event == "Exit_4" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            window.Close()
            break
        if event == "Exit APP" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            window.Close()  # New statement
            break
            
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
    window.close()
```

Comment: It better to revise your layout from `layout = [[[` to `layout = [[`.  Most of time, the container, like `Column`, won't reduce it size to minimum when no child element inside, better to use helper function `sg.pin` for element in the container, or put a tiny element inside the layout of a container, like Canvas(size=(1,1))`.

Comment: Can you give an example of that?, or alternatively change the layout of my code as you see fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code demo the difference between with and without `sg.pin` helper function.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

col_1 = [[sg.Multiline('Hello', size=(20, 5), key=('ML', '1'), metadata=True)]]
col_2 = [[sg.pin(sg.Multiline('World', size=(20, 5), key=('ML', '2'), metadata=True))]]

layout = [
    [sg.Button('ML1'), sg.Button('ML2')],
    [sg.Column(col_1)],
    [sg.Column(col_2)],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in ('ML1', 'ML2'):
        element = window[('ML', event[-1])]
        visible = element.metadata = not element.metadata
        element.update(visible=visible)

window.close()
```